# getting error on facebook catalog batch api on using app token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

api works for user token but does not when i put app token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<my-catalog-id>/batch?access_token=<my-app-token>&requests=[{"method": "UPDATE","retailer_id": "retailer-id","data":{"availability": "in stock", "price": "10", "currency": "USD"}}]
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '********' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id in ****** is your catalog id then your app must be missing permission. To access catalog, your app should have catalog_management and ads_management permissions. For better understanding you can refer this url. This document has example of real estate listings.

Comment: There does not seem to be an URL or link in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If the id in ****** is your catalog id then your app must be missing permission. To access catalog, your app should have `catalog_management` and `ads_management` permissions. For better understanding you can refer this [url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketplace/realestate). This document has example of real estate listings.